# Help setting up Galera Arbitrator

Tags: replication, mariadb, galera

I am testing a MariaDB Galera Cluster set up with only 2 nodes, I have three servers `haproxy, node1` and `node2` . I was able to set it up and it worked fine until testing phase.

There are two types of test that I made:

1. The main node fails
2. The second node fails

While testing I came across [this page](https://galeracluster.com/library/kb/two-node-clusters.html) which describes the problems.

So I was thinking of setting up garbd on both servers as what the guide said, but I don't think it is working(?)

Here is my garbd config:

```
group="galera-testing" 
address="gcomm://10.10.10.16,10.10.10.17"
options="gmcast.listen_addr=tcp://0.0.0.0:4444" 
log="/var/log/garbd.log"
```

If I run `sudo garbd --cfg /etc/garbd.cnf` the logs stop at: **Note: I started this on both servers**

```
INFO: (b363d915-923d, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4444') turning message relay requesting off
```

And I can't continue using the terminal without killing it.

Now, I'm thinking of two options:

- Setting garbd on my HAProxy Server making it act as the arbitrator **or**
- Setting garbd on both nodes (im confused as the guide says to set it on both servers? what??)

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

**Note:** I was able to test Galera Clusters with three nodes before + HAProxy, and it went better than with two nodes. But to satisfy my curiousity, I kinda want to learn this one works too.

Answer (score 0):

[Two node galera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400672/how-to-avoid-sst-in-mariadb-galera/62400748#62400748) is a fundamentally broken design as it cannot maintain uptime without a quorum and the ability of a node to go down to aid recovery.

garb is a toy test thing and not a production tool.

Use 3 nodes all as full galera member nodes.

Use haproxy in a redundant configuration on all nodes. Use a different IP addresses for haproxy and galera without overlap.

If it can't be reliable in test then it won't be reliable in production.

Comment: I see, I was just given three servers to test it, so can I use my HAProxy Server then as a third node then?

Comment: I can't see why not. I haven't see the specs however HAproxy or any tcp based proxy should be quite light weight. Don't forget to make that HA too with multiple instances. Possibly of interest is  [proxy support in mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/proxy-protocol-support/) for getting the client IP address. Its optional.

Comment: It's just twice the recommended specs for a standard CentOS system, just for testing purposes, resources will probably be reused when we apply the set up for production. I have already set up the back up node on my HAProxy Server, and it's much easier to start/stop the service. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My configuration works just fine, forgot to add port 4567 on each node IPs and removed the options.

```
group="galera-testing" 
address="gcomm://10.10.10.15:4567, 10.10.10.16:4567, 10.10.10.17:4567" 
log="/var/log/garbd.log"
```

Now my 2-node galera works. Even if one goes down, I can still transmit data to the database.